# Are nested If-Statements possible in Node-Red's Function Node?

Tags: node-red

Concerning the Function Node: It looks to me as if I can't use If-Elif-Else Statements inside other If's or Switch's.

Question: are nested If or Switch possible? Or is there a better way of implementing such thing in Nodered?

Example:

```
switch (msg.payload.auto)
{
case "Manuell":
    if (msg.payload.schattierung == "Ost")
    {
        var levelValue = "Schatten"
    }
    else if (msg.payload.schattierung == "Alle")
    {
        var levelValue = "Schatten"
    }
    else
    {
        var levelValue = "Offen"
    }

case "Auto":
    if (msg.payload.azimuth <= 225)
    {
        var levelValue = "Offen"
    }
    else if (msg.payload.azimuth < 235)
    {
        var levelValue = "Halb"
    }
    else
    {
        var levelValue = "Offen"
    }

default:
    var levelValue = "Offen"
}

var msgLevel = { payload: levelValue }

return msgLevel
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested If blocks or nested Switch/If blocks will work just fine, but you can also probably build something similar with a switch node and a collection of change nodes to set the values.

One thing to note, it's really inefficient and bad form to totally replace the incoming message with a new one in a function node. It is better to just replace the existing `msg.payload`. This also means that any nodes that use other keys on the `msg` object to keep state continue to work properly (e.g. http-response nodes needs the original message that is created by the http-in node to make it all the way down the flow to work properly)